# Wi-Fi will not connect to college wifi

Tags: wireless

I've recently dual booted the most recent Ubuntu with my Windows 10, I've never used Ubuntu before but I really want to get the hang of it. My Wi-Fi at home connects no problem. But when I go to my University and try to connect, it repeatedly tries to connect and then asks for authentication to which I need to put my password in. My password is definitely correct. And I have the CA certificate box checked to say I do not need a certificate. What in the world could be wrong?

I found an ask about the same situation and everyone said it was a bug that needed to be fixed, but this version is more recent then that post, wouldn't the bug have been fixed by now?

Comment: Some networks will require a CA certificate anyways. Have you tried adding your network's CA cert to Network Manager?

Comment: How do I go about that?  I found this tutorial but it stops working on my computer as I try to create an insecure key:https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/certificates-and-security.html

Comment: You need to download the CA certificate from your campus internet. Some campuses have a specific "setup" network that serves this file. If not, you're going to have to go in to see Campus IT and ask them for the CA cert. You don't generate your own.

Comment: Could you please include a link to the set-up instructions for the access to the wireless network in question? Is it an EDUROAM network by any chance?